# Losing data on a browser refresh in Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Background**

In a Vue.js application I am calling Getter VueX function in the mount life cycle method. This works great and retrieves all my customer data when the page loads.

The problem I seem to be facing is when I refresh the web page the mount method does not fire and the data is all removed from state which I have no access to till I navigate away from the page and then come back. At the point I return the mount function fires and I have the customer data back again.

**Example**

```
mounted() {
    this.getCustomers();
  },

async getSelected() {
      console.log("Customer ", this.customer.email);
      this.currentCustomer = this.customer;
      this.updateCustomerData.clientID = this.currentCustomer.client_id;
      this.updateCustomerData.email = this.currentCustomer.email;
      this.updateCustomerData.password = this.currentCustomer.password;
      this.customer = this.customer.email;
      await this.RECEIVE_CLIENT_NOTES(this.currentCustomer.client_id);
    },
```

That function above calls a VueX Getter to retrieve data that is used inside of a Material Auto Complete Search component. It fires off when I navigate to the page but does not fire at all when I am on the page and refresh. The refresh clears the state and leaves me without data on page reload.

**Question**

How should I handle page refreshes in order to maintain my data or recall the Getter from VueX to repopulate my data?

Comment: Strange.  Can you clarify what you're doing when you navigation away and come back?  Is this part of your app, or are you typing another URL into the address bar?

Comment: Seems like it looses current state on refresh. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: @JimB.I am using Vue router. When I click a link to leave the page then click the customers page link to return the mount function fires again. When I press cmd R on my mac while on the Customers page the Mount function does not fire.

Comment: @bigless Your suggestion absolutely solved my issue. Can you provide me with some type of explanation to why that was happening and why this npm module fixes it?

Comment: I dont know vue well, but all these frameworks handle navigation via routes(urls) and states connected to them. So the url is route to state. If some state is not associated with any url, it cannot be invoked by browser's navigation/refresh (unless you are using some plugin to store that in storage/cookies).