# How to maintain the cache when I return to the previous page using node / express?

Tags: typescript, express, caching, cache-control, memoization

I would like to know how I can implement a cache for a route, that keeps the data even when I go to another page.

I have the problem that when I'm on a particular route and I refresh the page, the data disappears and the content does not load because it is not in memory.

```js
import * as scraper from './scraper';
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/anime/:id/:chapter', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const id: string = req.params.id;
  const chapter: number = req.params.chapter;
  scraper.getAnimeVideo(id, chapter)
    .then(video => {
      res.status(200).json({
        video
      });
    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err)
    });
});


export default router;
```

Comment: This problem is likely a client-side problem in the browser (perhaps with the client-side Javascript).  The code for your route will offer the same response each time you request the same URL.  No server-side cache is needed for that.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00,

You are correct, the error comes from the client's side.
In that case I'm using vuejs as frontend.

Comment: Read the comments on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463647/losing-data-on-a-browser-refresh-in-vue-js-application.  In particular, see the link to the vuex-persistedstate module.

Comment: Also, a lot of discussion of this issue: https://www.google.com/search?q=vuejs+browser+refresh